# Auto fill postcode in checkout magento2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

Need to auto fill postcode in checkout by using below code, it shows error like "Postcode is required field ".

Can you help how to reslove this error, but it works properly in fresh magento2.

/etc/di.xml

/Plugin/Checkout/Model/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
    * @param array $jsLayout
    * @return array
    */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['firstname']['value'] = 'asf';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['lastname']['value'] = 'asf';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['company']['value'] = 'asf';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['city']['value'] = 'New York';


        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['postcode']['value'] = '223456';

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['telephone']['value'] = '1234567890';


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```